# boost mpi sends NULL messages

Tags: c++, string, boost, mpi

I am trying to send some MPI messages to a process using boost library. However, the receiver side cannot receive them properly. The receiver gets only NULL, instead of the real messages. My code is here:

```
// Receiver side, rank = 0
boost::mpi::communicator* world
// initialization of the world, etc...

map<int, string> messageMap;
map<int, boost::mpi::request> requestMap;
for(int j=1; j<world->size(); j++){
    requestMap[j] = world->irecv(j, 0, messageMap[j]);
}

for(typename map<int, boost::mpi::request>::iterator it = requestMap.begin(); it != requestMap.end(); it++){
    it->second.wait();
    cout << "Received message from " << j << " is: " << messageMap[j] << endl;
}


// Sender side, ranks = 1, 2 and 3
boost::mpi::communicator* world
// initialization of the world, etc...
world->isend(0, 0, "1");
```

Now, the problem is that receiver's output is similar to this:

```
Received message from 1 is: NULNUL
Received message from 2 is: NULNUL
Received message from 3 is: NULNUL
```

I could not figure out what the problem is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is in the underlying `boost::serialization`.

In your question you send a string literal "1" which has the C++ type `const char[2]`. `boost::serialization` serializes this as an array of size 2 (and NOT as a `std::string`). The receive then fails because `boost::mpi` tries to deserialize the array as a `std::string` and silently fails by returning null.

The solution,  as you already figured out,  is to send and receive the same type.  In this case a `std::string`.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know why, but it is fixed when I change the sender side like this:

```
// Sender side, ranks = 1, 2 and 3
boost::mpi::communicator* world
// initialization of the world, etc...
string s = "1";
world->isend(0, 0, s);
```

Comment: The last argument of `isend(0, 0, "1")` is a pointer to char while the last argument of `isend(0, 0, s)` is a `string` object.